# video chat using webrtc DOM exception 12

Tags: video, html5-video, livechat, webrtc

i'm trying out a simple video chat in a single web page using webrtc and am getting the following error
Uncaught Error: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12

my code is

```
    <button id='btn2' onclick='call();'>call</button>
    ...... 
    function call(){
        pc1 = new webkitPeerConnection00(null,icecallback1);
        console.log('created local peer connection object pc1');
        pc2 = new webkitPeerConnection00(null,icecallback2);
        console.log('created local peer connection object pc2');
        pc2.onaddstream = gotremotestream;

        pc1.addstream = localstream;
        console.log('loclastream added');
        var offer = pc1.createOffer(null);
        pc1.setLocalDescription(pc1.SDP_OFFER,offer);
        console.log('localdesc');
        pc2.setRemoteDescription(pc2.SDP_OFFER,offer);
        console.log('pc2remotedesc');

        var answer = pc2.createAnswer(offer.toSdp(),{has_audio:true,has_video:true});

        pc2.setLocalDescription(pc2.SDP_ANSWER,answer);
        pc1.setRemoteDescription(pc1.SDP_ANSWER,answer);

        pc1.startIce();
        pc2.startIce();

};

function gotremotestream(e){
    video2.src = webkitURL.createObjectURL(e.stream);
}

function icecallback1(candidate,bmore){
    if(candidate){
        pc2.processIceMessage(candidate);
        console.log("local ICE candidate: " + candidate.toSdp());
    }

}


function icecallback2(candidate,bmore){
    if(candidate){
        pc1.processIceMessage(candidate);
        console.log("remote ICE candidate: " + candidate.toSdp());
    }

}
```

can someone please help me out with my problem as i'm tottaly stumped by it?

Comment: just change the browser to chrome canary and it will work

Answer (score 0):

What version of Chrome are you using? Note the PeerConnection00 deprecation described at www.webrtc.org/blog.

Comment: i am using chrome 22..but running the code on canary solved my problem